# Translating C++ to python - memcpy uchar into int64

Tags: c++, python, int64

Alright, I'm copying some code (C++) that needs to run on my server (Python), everything was going well until the bit below.

In a nutshell here is what I have in the C++ program:

```
 int main() {
 ...
 ...
 int64 value = 0;
 bool blah = function1(&value);
 ...
 }

 bool function1(int64* value)
 {
 ...
 uchar pb[8];
 pb = '\x00\x00\x00\x00*Q \x00'; 
 memcpy(value,pb,8);
 //now value has the value '0x7fff33516970'
 }
```

So yeah, it creates some char array and then copies the value into an int64.

Now my **question** is: how do I do that in Python? I mean, I have the bytestring that is equivalent to pb but I have no idea where to go from there (especially since there are all those zeroes...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `struct` module, especially at `struct.unpack`. You can do:

`value, = unpack("q", string)`

"q" means 64-bit signed integer and string is simply a raw byte representation of the number. And remember, watch out the endianness!

Comment: I looked at struct but I get a different value than what I am expecting (on the same machine). 

unpack("Q", array) gives 9096440085217280 (but the value should be 140734054361456 )

Comment: The value of '0x7fff33516970' does not look right: print bin(long('0x7fff33516970',16)) gives 0b11111111111111100110011010100010110100101110000.

Comment: Well, true, `\x00\x00\x00\x00*Q \x00` is definitely not `0x7fff33516970`. @IamAlexAlright, how do you check the value of you number? Are you sure you're printing out `*value`, not `value` which would be just the address of your variable?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are used for characters, not strings in C++. Should be `"\x00\x00\x00\x00*Q \x00"`. Besides, the code makes little sense in that memory is allocated for `pb` and then it's overwritten with a constant string.

Comment: that's a good point; @IamAlexAlright, is your code the real code or just an example when you're trying to express what it should say?

Comment: @tomasz: just a paraphrase of the code - I can pastebin the whole thing if people really need to see it (but I don't think it has any bearing on my question)